# How to find week of a year for a given date for a given start of week other than Monday?

Tags: java, date, groovy, calendar, week-number

Suppose I set week start day as "Friday" in Java calendar variable .I need to find week number of the year similar to ISO week. Is there any simple way to find the week number?

Comment: [java Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR)

Comment: @jhamon No, please not. The `Calendar` class was always cumbersome to work with and was fortunately replaced by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) early 2014, eight and a half years ago. So use that instead. It offers a straightforward solution.

Comment: `LocalDate.of(2022, Month.SEPTEMBER, 28).get(WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 4).weekOfYear())`. Yields 39.  `WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 4)` means that the week starts on Friday and week 1 of the year is the first week with at least 4 days in the new year. You can substitute `WEDNESDAY` and `6` or which values you want.

Comment: @OleV.V. agreed, but the question says "calendar variable"

Comment: Sorry, @jhamon, indeed it does. So my message is more a recommendation for the OP. And everyone else reading along.

Answer (score 2):

## Define “week”

Since you want something other than a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) week, you must specify your definition of *week*.

For a [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object, pass to its `get` method a [`TemporalField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html) obtained from a [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) object.  You will need to specify which **day-of-week you consider to be first**, and specify the **minimum of days in a first week** of year. After that, you get back an `int` for week-of-year.

Ironically, easier done than said. Read on.

## `java.time.temporal.WeekFields`

The terrible `Calendar` & `GregorianCalendar` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

As [commented by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881024/how-to-find-week-of-a-year-for-a-given-date-for-a-given-start-of-week-other-than/73883966#comment130458564_73881127), you can use [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class for your purpose. Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date value (year, month, and day-of-month). Call [`WeekFields.of( DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek , int minimalDaysInFirstWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#of(java.time.DayOfWeek,int)).

```
LocalDate
.of( 2022 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 28 )   // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.get(
    WeekFields
    .of( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY , 4 )      // Returns a `WeekFields` object.
    .weekOfYear()                    // Returns a `TemporalField` object.
)                                    // Returns an `int` integer number, the week-of-year.
```

See this [code run at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nPwBlE).

> weekOfYear: 39

---

By the way, for those readers who *are* using a standard ISO 8601 week, I recommend adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project, for its [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged your question [groovy], here is a Groovy solution that worked for me. Let me know if it helps or not.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(6);
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
date=Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd","2022-01-05")

/* Set Your date whose week number is needed*/
calendar.setTime(date);
/* Get Similar to ISO8601 week number */
print calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); // Prints 1 

// All you need to set deviation as per your need, one solution can be by setting setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek as :-
// SUNDAY 3
// MONDAY 4
// TUESDAY 5
// WEDNESDAY 6
// THURSDAY 7
// FRIDAY 1
// SATURDAY 2
```

Comment: Whether it helps or not? Allow me to be honest, I’m afraid that it helps lead astray. I strongly recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `WeekFields`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to leverage the same.

Comment: @OleV.V. it is compiling and running for me. Try at https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-groovy-online/

Comment: I was thinking too much Java. As Groovy it works and prints `1`. And it is still outdated and not recommended.